# Need to create a button inside thumbnail-list using both php and html

Tags: php, html

So basicly i need to run a php function inside a thumbnail-list . When outside list and using only "text", it works. But if i convert to image, stops working and if inside the list doesn't work.When i press only main button works.
Function in question is ""

```
<div class="thumbnail-list">
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter-theme="d" data-inset="true">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php 
    if(get_option_tree('blog_exce','', false)!="")
    $length=get_option_tree('blog_exce','', false);
    else
    $length=100;
    $image_url=wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()) );
    $id = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'my_meta_box_text', true);
    if($id!="")
    ?>

    <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class("ui-btn-icon-right"); ?>>     
        <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li" aria-hidden="true">
           <div class="ui-btn-text">
            <a data-ajax="false" class="ui-link-inherit" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                    <p class="ui-li-aside ui-li-desc" ><?php the_time('Y-m-d') ?></p>
                <?php if($id!="") {?>
                    <img class="ui-li-thumb" src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" />
                    <?php }else {
                        if($meta2!="on"){?>
                    <div class="ui-li-thumb"><img style="display:none" class="blog_crop" src="<?php echo $image_url ; ?>" /></div>
                    <?php }else{?>
                    <div class="ui-li-thumb"><img style="max-height:80px;max-height:80px;" src="<?php echo $image_url ; ?>" /></div>

                    <?php }} ?>
                    <h3 class="ui-li-heading"><?php the_title()?></h3>
                    <a data-ajax="false" <?php wpfp_remove_favorite_link(get_the_ID());?> <img src="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/delete.png"></a>

            </a></div> 
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow"></span>    
    </div>
    </li>
```

[This is what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azbg8.jpg)

[This is what i want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xu3V.jpg)

Thank you all for the help!...
Note: the function removes post and refreshes page and needs be data-ajax="false"
the word "Remover" is the button